# How to use ReadFile with wchar_t?

Tags: c, winapi, utf-8, readfile

Consider the following two functions, the first one uses the Windows API functions `ReadFile()` and `CreateFileW()`, whereas the second function uses `fopen()` and `fgetws()`, to read a non-English text from a file called `data.txt`.

The first function outputs garbage text, whereas the second function outputs the text from the file without any problems.

Notice that `fopen()` has `ccs=UTF-8` that defines what character encoding to use, whereas `read_file_2()` does not have something similar.

```
DWORD read_file_2()
{
    wchar_t wstr[512];
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    DWORD dwRead, total =0;
    HANDLE handle = CreateFileW(L"data.txt",
                                GENERIC_READ,
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                3,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                NULL);
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return -1;
    do
    {   
        success = ReadFile(handle, wstr, 20, &dwRead, NULL);
        total += dwRead;
    } while(!success || dwRead == 0);

    wstr[total] = L'\0';
    wprintf(L"%ls\n",wstr);
    return 0;
}

void read_file_1()
{
    wchar_t converted[20];
    FILE * ptr;view=msvc-170
    ptr = fopen("data.txt", "rt+,ccs=UTF-8");
    fgetws(converted, 20, ptr);
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", converted);
    fclose(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    _setmode(fileno(stdin), _O_U8TEXT);
    _setmode(fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
    read_file_1();
    read_file_2();
}
```

How does one use `ReadFile()` to read a `wchar_t` string from a text file and output it to the terminal without turning it into garbage text?

```
 Шифрование.txt  ال
퀠킨톸톄킀킾킲킰킽킸♥
```

Actual content of `data.txt`:

```
 Шифрование.txt  العربية.txt
```

Comment: If `ReadFile` fails, what makes you think that it won't fail again next time you call it?

Comment: [There's No Such Thing As Plain Text](https://youtu.be/J8nblo6BawU).

Comment: @Dmitry `wchar_t` means **exactly** one thing when targeting the Win32 API.

Comment: @IInspectable Fair enough, I imagine too many programs rely on this behavior for it to ever reasonably stop being the case.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file?

Comment: @ikegami `UTF-8`

Comment: [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [MultiByteToWideChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar).

```c
#define MALLOC( t, n ) ( ( t* )malloc( sizeof( t ) * n ) )

int total_wchars = MultiByteToWideChar(
   CP_UTF8,       // CodePage
   0,             // dwFlags
   bytes,         // lpMultiByteStr  The bytes read using `ReadFile`/`read`.
   total_bytes,   // cbMultiByte        No need for NUL.
   NULL,          // lpWideCharStr
   0              // cchWideChar     0 = Get size incl NUL.
);

if ( total_wchars == 0 ) {
   // Error. Use GetLastError() and such.
   ...
}

LPWSTR wchars = MALLOC( WCHAR, total_wchars );

MultiByteToWideChar(
   CP_UTF8,       // CodePage
   0,             // dwFlags
   bytes,         // lpMultiByteStr
   total_bytes,   // cbMultiByte
   wchars,        // lpWideCharStr
   total_wchars   // cchWideChar
);
```

Note that if the compiler has `wchar_t`,

- `WCHAR` is `wchar_t`
- `LPWSTR` is `wchar_t *`
- `LPCWSTR` is `const wchar_t *`

Comment: Do I need to call `MultiByteToWideChar` twice ?

Comment: The first time tells you how much space you need to allocate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ReadFile()` doesn't read strings, or even characters. It reads *bytes*.

Since it doesn't read strings, it also doesn't *null-terminate* the data like a string.

You need to make sure that it reads enough bytes, and to null-terminate the buffer if it's a string.

---

By using a loop, you have a good start, but your loop overwrites what was read in the last iteration of the loop, making you lose the data.

You need to pass a pointer to the end of the buffer in the loop.

And as I already mentioned in a comment, make sure that the loop works properly (and not go into an infinite loop if there's an error, for example).

Comment: okay how do i output the bytes then

Comment: @loaded_dypper Make sure you read all of the contents of the file into the buffer (`wstr`), then add the terminator `L'\0'` at the end.

Comment: I updated the code, adding the null terminator does not help in outputting the right string

Comment: @loaded_dypper That is because you say the file is encoded in UTF-8, but you are reading in the raw bytes and *mis-interpreting* them, displaying them as-if they were encoded in UTF-16 instead. You need to read in the bytes and *convert* them from UTF-8 to UTF-16, as IInspectable and ikegami mentioned.